# Which direction will a truncated cone be pushed by airflow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, bernoulli-equation, aircraft

Consider the shape below, with the bottom and top faces being holes.

[image]

Imagine we hold the shape in place and blow a wind into the big hole.
The air will exit the small end at a higher velocity due to Bernoulli's Principle.
Because the air is exiting at a higher velocity than which it entered, the shape will experience a net force in the direction the wind is coming from.
So, if we let the shape go, it will accelerate in the direction against the wind.

This must be wrong, though. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cone is hit by molecules of air.

These molecules exert forces e.g. $F$ and they have a components in the direction of the wind.  So the cone should receive a force in the direction of the wind.

[image]

Since $v_2$ is bigger than $v_1$ from the continuity condition, it's natural to wonder if there is an 'equal and opposite force' from Newton's 3rd Law, acting in the opposite direction to the wind.

There is, a force has acted on the molecules behind the ones leaving at $B$, so that the molecules further back in the cone and near $A$ have been slowed down to a speed $v_1$.  They would initially have had the speed $v_3$.

The forces that speed up some molecules to $v_2$ and slow down others to $v_1$ are due to the millions of collisions taking place between the molecules.